# Cortex-A8 Get C Variable

Tags: c, assembly, arm, cortex-a8

I am a total newby when it comes to assembly. But I need to load the address of a C variable in order to save the values of the registers into it. I have to save them, because I need the data for an interrupted process. My IRQ handler may alter the registers and the stack, therefore I have to save them temporarly. I decided to save the registers into a global variable.

My problem is that I don't know how to reference the variable __context_current (see second line in __context_save_tmp).

```
;
; Context.asm
;
        .global __context_save_tmp

; Save the context of the interrupted process into the temporary __context_current variable
__context_save_tmp:
    STMFD R13!, {R12}               ; Temporarly save R12 in Stack
    LDR R12, =__context_current     ; Load the address of the context variable in R12
    STMEA R12!, {R0-R11}            ; Save Registers R0-R11 in context variable
    MOV R5, R12                     ; Move address of context variable to register R5
    LDMFD R13!, {R12}               ; Get the original R12 value from the stack
    STMEA R5!, {R12}                ; Store R12 to the context variable
```

The variable __context_current is defined in a C file. It's type is a struct, containing all registers.

```
/*
 * Context.h
 */

typedef struct {
    uint32_t R0;    //< R0
    uint32_t R1;    //< R1
    uint32_t R2;    //< R2
    uint32_t R3;    //< R3
    uint32_t R4;    //< R4
    uint32_t R5;    //< R5
    uint32_t R6;    //< R6
    uint32_t R7;    //< R7
    uint32_t R8;    //< R8
    uint32_t R9;    //< R9
    uint32_t R10;   //< R10
    uint32_t R11;   //< R11
    uint32_t R12;   //< R12
    uint32_t SP;    //< R13, Stack Pointer
    uint32_t LR;    //< R14, Link Register
    uint32_t PC;    //< Program Counter
    uint32_t CPSR;  //< Mode
 } Registers_t;

Registers_t __context_current;
```

I get multiple compile errors:

```
[E0001] Illegal symbol
[E0003] Unexpected trailing operand(s)
[E0200] Bad term in expression  
#10010 errors encountered during linking; "project.out" not built
#10056 symbol "__context_current" redefined: first defined in "./main.obj"; redefined in "./src/system/scheduler/scheduler.obj"
#10234-D unresolved symbols remain
```

Comment: Isn't this working as is ? What is the error you get ? Also, never declare a variable in a .h. Declare it in a .c.

Comment: XY problem? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: I hope you meant the other "d" word there @ElderBug  (i.e. _define_)  :-)

Comment: Good point, I completely forgot to mention the errors. I added them at the end of the question...

Comment: @auselen It's really about how to reference that variable and how to save data from the registers to it. I need it, because I need the state at a specific point and my registers and stack may get altered. There may be alternative ways to solve this - and probably also better ways. But I need a solution for the described problem.

Comment: well you don't mention if this is on top of an existing OS, your own roll, if you are in user or system context...

Comment: Fair enough. This should be part of our context switch and I am in the IRQ mode. We don't have an existing OS, instead we are writing our own - Its for studying purposes. The interrupted process will be in a user mode, but at the moment they are in system mode. Because our IRQ handler may do other stuff as well and alter the registers, I need to save them somewhere. Saving it on the stack is an option, but I cannot assure other things will be pushed atop it, therefore I decided to save it somewhere else.